# How to create mysql database table in Qt?

Tags: mysql, qt

I want to create table to mysql database.I am able to successfully open database but the query which contains create table command not working?
if anybody know about it please let me know i'll be grateful.

```
mydb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
mydb.setDatabaseName("mylogin");

mydb.setUserName("root");
mydb.setPort(3306);
mydb.setHostName("localhost");
mydb.setPassword("");

if(!mydb.open())
{
   qDebug() << "failed" ;
   qDebug() << mydb.lastError().text();
}
QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("CREATE TABLE RSA(name varchar(20);");
if(qry.exec())
{
   QMessageBox msg;
   msg.setText("Data saved");
   msg.exec();
   mydb.close();
   mydb.removeDatabase(QSqlDatabase::defaultConnection);
 }
 else
 {
    QMessageBox msg2;
    msg2.setText("Failed to save data");
    msg2.exec();
    qDebug() << mydb.lastError().text();
 }
}
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: I have edited my post check it once

Comment: and what is the error returned?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have a syntax error in your SQL statement, you're missing the final closing parenthesis.

Secondly, for your purposes, you do not need to prepare your SQL statement in order to use it, you could simply execute it.

```
QSqlQuery qry;
if(qry.exec("CREATE TABLE RSA(name varchar(20))"))
{
//....
```

Answer (score 0):

**First:** You have to check QSqlQuery::prepare return value first. Following is signature:

```
bool QSqlQuery::prepare ( const QString & query )
```

**Second:** What is mysql autocommit value for your connection? If default auto commit is 0 then you have to call `QSqlDatabase::commit` after query excution. Or set auto commit value to 1 during database connection initialization.

Comment: Autocommit status does NOT affect DDL queries in MySQL, so your answer cannot be correct